# where is the error in this RowMapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have this Request `SQL` :

```
private List<IWsResponse> getBPartnerDetails(String valueNetwork, String reportLevel2) {

            JdbcTemplate tm = new JdbcTemplate(ds.getDataSource());
            StringBuffer sql =  new StringBuffer("SELECT * FROM XRV_BPARTNERDETAILS order by BPartner_ID");

            ArrayList<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();

            response = tm.query(sql.toString(), new BPartnerMapper());

            return response;

        }
```

i create a new RowMapper (BPartnerMapper) like this

```
public class BPartnerMapper implements RowMapper<IWsResponse> {

        @Override
public List<IWsResponse> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

            List<IWsResponse> bps    = new ArrayList<IWsResponse>();

            while (rs.next()) {

                    bp = new BPartner();
                                      bp.setBPartnerValue(rs.getString("BPartnerValue"));

                //adress
                    adr = new Adress();
                    adr.setBPartnerLocation_ID(BPartner_Location_ID);
                    bp.getAdress().add(adr);

                //user
                    usr = new User();
                    usr.setUser_ID(User_ID);
                    bp.getUsers().add(usr);

                    bps.add(bp)
            }

            return bps;
    }
```

the Class BPartner is

```
public class BPartner implements IWsResponse {

    private String BPartnerValue;

    private ArrayList<Adress> adress = new ArrayList<Adress>();

    private ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

}
```

so i get this Error

[image]

```
The return type is incompatible with RowMapper<IWsResponse>.mapRow(ResultSet, int)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html). A row mapper maps objects for a single row.

> This method should not call next() on the ResultSet; it is only supposed to map values of the current row.

So your return type should be IWsResponse rather than List. Additionally you must only map the current row. Not all of them.